# What is rmeta files and how to see their contents?

Tags: rust, rmeta

Rust creates `.rmeta` files. What is this and how to see their contents? For `.rlib` files, I could use `nm` to see their contents. But I have no idea for `.rmeta` files.

Comment: Maybe this [link](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/63224) is useful for you

Answer (score 2):

> An rmeta file is custom binary format that contains the metadata for the crate. This file can be used for fast "checks" of a project by skipping all code generation (as is done with cargo check), collecting enough information for documentation (as is done with cargo doc), or for pipelining. This file is created if the --emit=metadata CLI option is used.

> rmeta files do not support linking, since they do not contain compiled object files.

See https://rustc-dev-guide.rust-lang.org/backend/libs-and-metadata.html for details.